# Identify Removable Storage Path in Android

Tags: android, storage, android-file

My question is quite simple.

In my app, the user can browse both the Internal and Removable storage of their device and select files from both the place.

Now while writing back data I need to know if the file has been taken from the Internal or the Removable storage.

How is it possible to identify is the file has been taken from the Internal or Removable storage?

Comment: Concentrate on *why* you need to know and it will probably lead to *the most applicable* answer.  Bear in mind that on Android "Internal" refers to the app's private data folder, while "External" can refer to either a permanent volume or a removable one.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes that I know. I want to identify from which location the file was taken, from the on-board storage of the device or the removable one. Is that possible?

Comment: There are things that work in a lot of cases, but none which are perfectly portable.  The key is determined by what you want to do with the information, as whatever you wish to do differently based on it will give you a set of properties which you can check (don't care about where it is, care about what you need to do differently because of the properties resulting from where it is).  And of course if you knew which they were browsing when they picked it, your simplest approach of all would be to just remember that.